# What does the phrase "in critical terms" mean in this sentence?

Tags: meaning

While the decision of the Permanent Court is a fundamental milestone in the crystallization
of the doctrine of implied powers, some authors have assessed the performance of
the Court **in critical terms**.

Answer (score 2):

In this context, it appears to be essentially a roundabout way of saying "Some authors have been critical of the performance of the Court" or "Some authors have criticised the performance of the Court".